# Laravel not discovering package I am developing

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php

I am developing a package but somehow I am not able to make Laravel to discover it.

Package is on the root of the app and follows the next structure:

[image: Package structure]

Files:

**StatusManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Troyerx\StatusManager;

trait StatusManager {
  //Code
}
```

**Composer.json** in *packages/troyerx/statusmanager*/

```
{
    "name": "troyerx/statusmanager",
    "description": "Simple model status manager",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": [
        "troyerx",
        "php",
        "statusmanager"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sergio",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Mi app composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\": "packages/troyerx/statusmanager/src/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\": "packages/troyerx/statusmanager/src/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Since the package is marked to be discover on the autoload, I should expect to get it included when I run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But I get the following prompt:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   INFO  Discovering packages.  

  laravel/sail ................................................................................................................................ DONE
  laravel/sanctum ............................................................................................................................. DONE
  laravel/tinker .............................................................................................................................. DONE
  nesbot/carbon ............................................................................................................................... DONE
  nunomaduro/collision ........................................................................................................................ DONE
  nunomaduro/termwind ......................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-ignition ..................................................................................................................... DONE

Generated optimized autoload files containing 5729 classes
```

If I call for the trait in a model its not autoloaded

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Troyerx\StatusManager\StatusManager as StatusManager;

class Order extends Model
{
    use StatusManager;
}
```

Gives next error:

```
Trait "Troyerx\StatusManager\StatusManager" not found
```

Why Laravel its not loading my package? Which step I am missing or where is the problem?

Comment: You dont really have an `package` here. You just added an `autoload` definition for your classes. You may have your own package in that subfolder, but then you have to include it not only by adding an `autoload` entry.  I thing `package:discover` is only needed for real packages that are hosted on github. But its hard to explain, read here more about it: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages.md#usage  Only stuff under `"require"` is checked by `package:discover`

Comment: Check it with `composer dump-autoload -vvv` to see if something went wrong. But this becomes a debuging session.. :-) Hopefully you can get this fixed. I didn't downvote, but you added really late the real issue that the trait can not be loaded. So you mixing more than one issue here: package:discover thing and triat not loaded thing. So it hard to help.

Comment: Still having same issue, composer dont discover my package, I dont know which step I am skipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, to make Laravel to discover/install my package when I run `composer dump-autoload`.

In the app composer.json I added:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/troyerx/statusmanager",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],
```

And added in the require-dev the next line:

```
"require-dev": {
    ...
    "troyerx/statusmanager": "@dev"
},
```

After running `composer update` the package is discover:

```
INFO  Discovering packages.  

laravel/sail ................................................................................................................................ DONE
laravel/sanctum ............................................................................................................................. DONE
laravel/tinker .............................................................................................................................. DONE
nesbot/carbon ............................................................................................................................... DONE
nunomaduro/collision ........................................................................................................................ DONE
nunomaduro/termwind ......................................................................................................................... DONE
spatie/laravel-ignition ..................................................................................................................... DONE
troyerx/statusmanager ....................................................................................................................... DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

So, your package's `composer.json` should be like this:

```json
{
    "name": "troyerx/statusmanager",
    "description": "Simple model status manager",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "keywords": [
        "troyerx",
        "php",
        "statusmanager"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sergio",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

See that I have:

- Added a require (Laravel Framework), so it depends on Laravel (if it is pure PHP, remove it)
- I have also added `version`, so you can keep track of version and it is easier

Your main `composer.json` should be like this (I will list the sections I have changed or added):

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "troyerx/statusmanager": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/"
        },
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I have:

- Removed your custom namespace from `autoload` and `autoload-dev`
- Added a normal `require` with a version constraint
- Added `repositories` section in the file linking to what folder it should look it up

So, first edit your package's composer file, then add the `repositories` to your main composer file, and then use the command line to do `composer require troyerx/statusmanager:^1.0` and done, it will automatically be picked.

Remember to bump the package's composer version (`version` section) to a new version, and then just run `composer update troyerx/statusmanager` in your main composer and done!

This is the composer documentation I have used: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

---

One thing to have in mind: if you are developing a Laravel package, you should not have `database` and `factories` inside `src`, but outside, and then have that package's `composer.json` like this:

```json
{
    "name": "troyerx/statusmanager",
    "description": "Simple model status manager",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "keywords": [
        "troyerx",
        "php",
        "statusmanager"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sergio",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\": "src/",
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Troyerx\\Statusmanager\\Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to have your own `ServiceProvider` and add it to the package's composer `extra -> laravel` section, like this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/blob/4dc20b028adaeadf603860f179f09da5aa21f5b5/composer.json#L70-L74

Use that development package as guide on how to implement your own package, it should look like very similar (at least with your files, but structure wise).

Use [Laravel Jetstream](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream) (for example), to see how to load the migrations. Do follow it as an example.

Have in mind that all Laravel packages are like those 2, so if you know a package, go to github and see the structure is has and what it has in `composer.json`, etc. Follow that!